# Need block div come right to existing div

Tags: html

I have a div with css like this

## container #homepage{display:block; width:50%;}

I want one more div which should come right side to this div with same width, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
display:inline-block;
```

but it's not compatible withsome older browsers

Comment: No, it does not work, it came on top of the that div                      #container #homepage1{display:inline-block; width:50%;} this is what I tried

Comment: did you use inline-block on both divs? display:block means that block elements are layed out one after another vertically. Divs are block elements so you must explicitly change the display to inline-block for all block elements you want to display horizontally.